# The cypress-testrail-reporter couldn't submit results

Tags: cypress, testrail

I have made a simple test and configured configs for the cypress-testrail-reporter.
But what I noticed is that it do open new test run, but it couldn't publish results.  I am using 1.2.2 version of cypress-testrail-reporter. And I am using node 15.0.0v.

Here is the error log I got from the cypress after running `npx cypress run`.

````
 {
  config: {
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
    transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.1',
      'Content-Length': 77
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://example.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined',
    auth: { username: 'USERNAME', password: 'PASSWORD' },
    data: '{"results":[{"case_id":2255,"status_id":1,"comment":"Execution time: 35ms"}]}'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 6,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'example.testrail.io',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'example.testrail.io',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: false,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 2544,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'POST /index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.18.1\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 77\r\n' +
      'Host: example.testrail.io\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Basic cWFAZ2V0YXdhaXIuY29tOj15JnRnOndASFtELTdAZEQ=\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'fifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'example.testrail.io',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 77,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array],
      authorization: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      date: 'Thu, 26 Aug 2021 08:06:02 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '44',
      connection: 'close',
      server: 'Apache',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'authorization, content-type, x-api-ident',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://testrail-lite.testrail.io',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      vary: 'Origin'
    },
    config: {
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Object],
      transformResponse: [Object],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://example.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined',
      auth: [Object],
      data: '{"results":[{"case_id":2255,"status_id":1,"comment":"Execution time: 35ms"}]}'
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.18.1\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 77\r\n' +
        'Host: example.testrail.io\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic cWFAZ2V0YXdhaXIuY29tOj15JnRnOndASFtELTdAZEQ=\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/undefined',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'example.testrail.io',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: { error: 'Field :run_id is not a valid ID.' }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Did you manage to sort this issue out, still facing it?

Comment: @Gudzo I solved this issue by installing other test reporter.

Comment: That sounds great, which one did you used? I tried cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter but no luck.

Comment: @Gudzo I don't really remember since I was doing that project 6 months ago. But I think it was mocha-testrail-reporter. Try it and if it works notify me.